# Not able to give build permission to device on TestFlight

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, testflight

I want to give build permission to a particular device on TestFlight.

I have added that device on developer.apple.com and also added to provisioning profile I have uploaded to TestFlight. Also I have uploaded that profile to TestFlight.

I am able to add all other devices but not this particular device. On TestFlight it shows this device under `Teammate devices not on this profile` section. It does not show check box i.e. I can't add this device to build. :

[image]

How can I solve it?

**Update :** Below is what I tried but did not work unfortunately.

1. Created a new adhoc profile.
2. Removed all Xcode profiles and refreshed them to have newly created profile in Xcode.
3. Set `Build Settings->Code signing identity->Provisioning profile` to this new ad hoc profile.
4. Created .ipa signed with new profile and uploaded build to TestFlight.
5. Uploaded new profile to TestFlight.

Comment: Double check you AdHoc profile, since this message means that the UDID of this test device is not in the profile supplied for this app,

Comment: @rckoenes Its there in profile.

Comment: TestFlight parse the profile from your app and matches to devices. The messages means that this users UDID is **NOT** in the profile. You could try and just update the profile of this app, sometimes the build process of Xcode might use an old profile.

Comment: @rckoenes I tried this. Please see my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new profile on Apple's dev site. Name it something DIFFERENT from the current name. I usually append the date to mine so I KNOW which is which. Then, make sure you select the new one when building. If you have multiples with the same name it's a guessing game as to which one Xcode will choose when building your app. @rckoenes is correct - the UDID is NOT in the profile that is in the app that you uploaded to TestFlight. Using unique names will help alleviate this problem.

Comment: I tried creating new profile. But still having same issue. See my updated question where I have mentioned step-wise what I tried.

Answer (score 0):

Add device UDID to devices on developer.apple.com then recreate developer provisioning profile   and download it.After open it choose provisioning profile in XCode->targets->CodeSigning.Archive project and upload it to testFlight.

Comment: You mean regenerate the profile or create a separate one?

Comment: Can I set XCode->targets->CodeSigning->Provisioning profile to distribution profile and sign archive with adhoc profile and will it work?